# Evenness of binomial co coefficients for power $2^n$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I've noticed that all binomial coefficients, apart from first and last, for powers 1, 2, 4 and 8 are even numbers. This suggests, that it may be the case for any $2^n$.

In other words, is the following true?

> $\binom{2^n}{k}$ is even for any *natural* $k<2^n$

Comment: You can go further: Given ay prime $p$, $p$ divides $\binom{p^n}{m}$ for any $m, n$ with $1\leq m\leq p^n-1$. It all comes down to the number of factors $p$ in a given factorial. Do you know how to tell that number?

Comment: Yes. ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: Can you prove it, or give a link to the proof?

Comment: @cyanide I realized now that your question is already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317163/prove-if-n-2k-1-then-binomni-is-odd-for-0-leq-i-leq-n

Comment: Special case of [Prime dividing the binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/prime-dividing-the-binomial-coefficients)